# Margin before text in h1

Tags: html, css

how can I add some **space** before "Sample Text" using *CSS*? For example `margin-left:20px;` but it does not work properly. Background should stay where it is. I do not want use `&nbsp;` in HTML!
**There is my fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gSVfV/293/

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="post-title entry-title">Some Text</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1.post-title.entry-title {
background-image: url('http://www.forkingandcountry.com/sites/g/files/g2000004371/f/styles/news_landing_image/public/sample_03.jpg?itok=rk7nkdNu');
color: white;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: While including a fiddle is nice, you should include the code from the fiddle as part of your question so that in the event that the fiddle disappears your question is still useful.

Comment: @drneel You are right, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `padding-left` property to add some *padding* on the left. See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m23ajh1c/).

Read more about padding at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Comment: Yep. Works. Thanks a lot.